# Watir magic escape sequence?

Tags: ruby, firefox, watir

I am currently using Watir with Firefox and it seems that when I try to set a field with the following text:

> @#$QWER7890uiop

The command I am using is the following:

> text_field(:name, "password").value=("!@#$QWER7890uiop)

I've also tried this:

> text_field(:name, "password").set "!@#$QWER7890uiop)

Only the first 2 characters get entered.  Is there something I can do to by pass this feature?

Comment: I have a vague memory that ! can cause trouble (it may have been using autoit with watir though). Try moving the ! to the end and see if you get more characters.

Comment: It would help to see what you've actually tried.

The first example above has an unclosed ", the second has an extra ) and an unclosed ".

Have you tried setting a different field (i.e., "username") with the password string to see what watir is actually putting into the field?  That would likely help you a lot in debugging this yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the string using single quotes `'`.

```
text_field(:name, "password").value='"!@#$QWER7890uiop'
```

Many characters are substituted inside double quotes.

1. Escape sequences like \n, \t, \s, etc are replaced by their equivalent character(s). See [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#Backslash_Notation) for full list.
2. `#{}` where anything the braces is interpreted as a ruby expression.
3. `#$something` where `$something` is interpreted as a ruby global variable. That's the problem with your quote above, beside not being terminated.
4. `%s` is interpreted as an ERB template expression (it is interpolated). 
   For instance:
   `puts "%s hours later" % 'Five'`
   results in
   `"Five hours later"`.

Comment: Which characters need to be escaped?  Is it the!  That causes issues?

Comment: I've just added the list I know of on the answer above.